# Creating a list from a variable holding changing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a tkinter application, wherein I do save the process done in UI using "Save" button. Below is the sample part of my code for better understanding:

```
self.savebtn = Button(self.btm_frm,text="Save",width=10,command=self.savebutton)

def savebutton(self):
    self.savelist=[]
    self.savetext = r" Item - " + str(self.a) + " is done "
    self.savelist.append(self.text)
```

So every time I click on "Save" button, it would call `self.savebutton` command which actually saves some text. And I want to create a list that would record all the values of `self.savetext` But I am stuck at creating list of whole data, since I am not familiar with this case, and the above code could retain only the list of last call. Can anyone guide on achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move:

```
self.savelist=[]
```

to the `__init__` scope of your class, so that its created as empty list only *once* and then appended each time `savebutton` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your

> self.savelist

before your function is called so that your list is only created once.